# Cannot open database “databaseName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, connection-string, asp.net-core-2.1

I have created a .NET Core 2.1 project and after I publish the project to the server and try to call an API, I got this error:

> Cannot open database "databaseName" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user.

Note that when I run the project locally on the server everything was ok.

This is my connection string:

```
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=databaseName;User ID=myUserId;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

I hope someone can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server **Express** installed locally on the remote web server, too - as instance `SQLEXPRESS` ?? If not, you might need to change your connection string to reflect the new situation on the server

Comment: Log into the instance and get the error from there; that'll tell you the true error. Though your connection string makes little sense. You're supplying a UID and Password **and** stating the connection is trusted; it can't be both. The UID and Password will be ignored in the above connection string. You aren't  trying to pass Domain Credentials as if they are a SQL Authentication login, are you?

Comment: @marc_s  yes it's installed locally on the remote web server, and everything was perfect when running the project locally in the visual studio from the remote web server.

Comment: My guess is that login doesn't have the necessary rights to the specified database. Note, that with `Trusted_Connection=True` you are probably using Windows authentication. Use `Trusted_Connection=False` to connect using SQL authentication.

Comment: The database has credentials and when running local and running on the server you need to use the same credentials.Trusted Connections is using the Windows credentials of the user that is login.For trusted connections to work you need the user to have the same account on the local machine and the remote machine.When using a username/password the server has to allow the username/password credentials.Also the database credentials have to allow the user access.The best way of debugging is to use SQL Server Management Studio and get working before trying c#.  Error message are much better in SSMS.

Comment: @Zhorov
Thank you for your help, after I change the Trusted_Connection to False everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved after change `Trusted_Connection=True` to  `Trusted_Connection=False` to connect using SQL authentication.